# ¿Cómo crear botones en android sin XML?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego en android en dónde necesito hacer un tablero (hecho de botones).

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de crearlo desde mi clase java sin tener que usar el XML, es decir, dentro de un `loop` crear todos los botones, asignarles posición y tambien id.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código creo que es lo que buscas:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  //Can also be done in xml by android:orientation="vertical"

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++ {
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * 4));
        btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
        row.addView(btnTag);
    }

    layout.addView(row);
}
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195056/how-do-i-programmatically-add-buttons-into-layout-one-by-one-in-several-lines